# Android Webview stop loading at 90% progress after JS injection

Tags: java, android, mobile, webview

I am having a ViewPager with WebViews containing some HTML content and JS.

When I call the following:

```
public void goToAnchor(String hash) {
    this.loadUrl("javascript:alert(myapp.getAnchorOffset(\'"+hash+"\'));");
}
```

it runes the javascript correctly, and inside my WebChromeClient I listen to an alert created in the "getAnchorOffset" JS function, like this:

```
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {

            //Set the page
            int offset = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(message));

            Log.d("Anchor - ", "Offset = " + offset);
            Log.d("Anchor - ", "width = " + mWebView.getWidth());

            //Get the page
            int page = Math.round(offset / mWebView.getWidth());

            //Make the callback
            anchorListener.didGetAnchorPage(page);
            return true;
        }
```

This also gets called correctly, and I get the correct value in the variable "page". Now the funny/annoying part is that when I make the callback with anchorListener.didGetAnchorPage, it does callback, but all the following webViews I am using will not load, and progress stops at 90%.

Like if I to go to page 20 in the ViewPager, the WebView will stop loading at 90%, and this always happens after the JS call I make.

The JS function getting called is this:

```
myapp.getAnchorOffset = function(elementId) {
var searchResult = $(document).find("#"+elementId).first();
if (searchResult.length == 0) {
    console.log("ERROR - no DOM element found by id: " + elementId);
    return 0;
}
return searchResult.offset().left;
```

};

Do anybody know why??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just noticed that if I change the return value of onJsAlert to true, then it actually renders the other pages, but it also shows the alert, and that is not supposed to happen. How can one fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

The trick is to handle the js alert like the following:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {

            //Set the page
            int offset = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(message));

            Log.d("Anchor - ", "Offset = " + offset);
            Log.d("Anchor - ", "width = " + mWebView.getWidth());

            //Get the page
            int page = Math.round(offset / mWebView.getWidth());

            //Make the callback
            anchorListener.didGetAnchorPage(page + pageInEpub);
            result.cancel();
            return true;
        }
```

With the "result.cancel();" before the return statement.